# ng build has some file not found

Tags: angular-cli

when I ng build, 
some files(ex: woff2、woff、json) was existed, 
but my website doesn't know them.
How can I do?

[1. web error 404 pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c57oJ.png)

---

[2. ng build pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCMss.png)

---

my .angular-cli.json

```
"assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
```

Comment: I solved this problem.
In IIS you can declare the mime type for WOFF2 font files by adding the following to your project's web.config:


<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
    <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="font/woff" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.
In IIS you can declare the mime type for woff、woff2、json files by adding the following to your project's web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="font/woff" />
    <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
    <remove fileExtension=".json" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```